# 1hr time limit on tokens used for server-server authentication

Tags: google-oauth

Tokens obtained via OAuth 2.0 for service accounts expire after 1 hour.

If an HTTP session is still open while the 1 hour limit is reached (presumably due to many upload/download actions), will the connection stay alive until the session is closed?

Thanks.

--Lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using OAuth to authenticate users in your website, you probably are not even using the token after the initial exchange with the OAuth provider. Most frameworks will create a cookie based session, for how long this session is valid is up to your setup. Usually the default is to keep the session while the browser is open, but it is really under your control.

On the other side, if you are using OAuth to access some API (for example, if you are using the GMail API to check or send email from inside your web application), then yes, you will not be able to access the API after the token is expired, no matter how much activity was seen while the token was fresh. If you want to keep authorized you need something like a background process to keep renewing the tokens before they expire.